# How can I reference a vector within a list for an sapply function?

Tags: r, sapply

x is a large list with 43 elements. I want to do the following 43 times (from 1 to 43).

`activity_stats(x[[1]][["VECTORMAGNITUDECOUNTS"]], x[[1]][["TIMESTAMPTZ"]])`

I tried using sapply but can't figure out syntax:

`x2 <- sapply(x, activity_stats(x[[i]][["VECTORMAGNITUDECOUNTS"]], x[[i]][["TIMESTAMPTZ"]]))`

I'm trying to reference the two highlighted columns, which have the same names inside each of the 43 list elements.

[image]

Comment: `sapply(x, function(d) activity_stats(d$VECTORMAGNITUDECOUNTS, d$TIMESTAMPTZ))`

Comment: `sapply(x, function(y) activity_stats(y[["VECTORMAGNITUDECOUNTS"]], y[["TIMESTAMPTZ"]]))`??